# How to override Woocommerce functionality in Reports section?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, pluggable

I need to customize the Reports in WooCommerce, so I have to edit the core file `class-wc-report-sales-by-date.php`, such file doesn't use any hook.

Check: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-report-sales-by-date.php

I have to edit the 393 line, this variable: **$this->report_data->total_sales**
I need to customize the **Total Sales** amount to add it another value.

How can I override WooCommerce this core file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? Look at this `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_report_data', $this->report_data );`

Comment: @Drupalizeme Thanks for your time. What can I do with that filter?

Comment: 1) View it to get the output of the report_data 2) Use it to change the data example `add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_report_data', 'your_function' );`.